# Why can't I get list to access a class, properly?

Tags: python

I'm new to Python. I'm making a basic list that has access to a class. But when I send it to the output, the terminal lists it as a basic object, instead of each class item seperately.
Here is the code:

```
     # Make a class with attributes
    class Persons(object):
         def __init__(self, firstName=None, lastName=None):
            self.firstName = firstName
            self.lastName = lastName

    # Make list with said attributes
        def newList():
            nameList = []
            nameList.append(Persons("Mathew", "Dodson"))
            nameList.append(Persons("Dr", "Kin"))

    # Print out said list

           print(str(nameList.firstName))
           print(str(nameList.lastName))

     newList()
```

I'm pretty sure I have the syntax entirely wrong some way. If anyone could help, that would be appreciated.

Comment: Your indentation is all over the place. Please reformat your question so that it is exactly the same as your actual code.

Comment: You need to be more clear about your expected output; a [MCVE] needs to provide a sample of expected output, along with the observed (wrong) output. As is, your description of the problem implies you're seeing the default `repr` of your `Persons` objects, but your code would throw an `AttributeError`.

Comment: Fix your indentation. This does not run as python code.

Comment: I was able to fix it. The indentation was out of control because I don't use stack overflow much so I'm still figuring out how to set it into code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`nameList` is a list - it contains `Person` objects. `nameList.firstname` will not work. You will need to select one of those `Person`s inside nameList, and then access the attributes. For example:

```
# Print out said list

print(str(nameList[0].firstName)) # Mathew
print(str(nameList[1].lastName))  # Kin
```

If you want to print out the whole list:

```
for person in nameList:
    print(person.firstName)
    print(person.lastName)
```

Answer (score 2):

### Make the list

To make list you don't need to do successive appends, just declare it in one go like so:

```py
name_list = [Persons('Mathew', 'Dodson'), Persons('Dr', 'Kin')]
```

### Iterate the list

The list itself has no `first_name` attribute. But the elements do.

```py
for person in name_list:
    print(person.first_name)
    print(person.last_name)
```

*I'm sorry to change your naming convention, but everyone uses snake case in python. You may explore further in [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).*

Answer (score 0):

`nameList` is a `list`, `list`s don't have a `firstName` or `lastName` attribute (there is no magic by which `list`s automatically access attributes of their members).

Similarly, you say "the terminal lists it as a basic object, instead of each class item separately." That's because just like `list`s, object's have a `repr` that's fairly uninformative, but unlike `list`s, you can customize it.

If the goal is to print out each person's first name and last name, you could do something like:

```
 for person in nameList:
     print(person.firstName, person.lastName)  # Separates with a space
```

You could also achieve this by defining a `__str__` or `__repr__` for your class such that a more useful string form is produced automatically, e.g.:

```
class Persons(object):
    def __init__(self, firstName=None, lastName=None):
        self.firstName = firstName
        self.lastName = lastName
    def __repr__(self):
        return 'Persons({!r}, {!r})'.format(self.firstName, self.lastName)
    def __str__(self):
        return '{} {}'.format(self.firstName, self.lastName)
```

which would allow you to get the same results as the first loop I described with just:

```
 for person in nameList:
     print(person)  # __str__ is called automatically, and you made it return something useful
```